# Automatically refreshing ArcGIS93Rest layer in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server, rest

I finally succeeded to import a gtfs-realtime feed into ArcGIS Server (used gtfsrdb.py and the created a script to automatically, every 30 seconds, to update the geometry of a table with the points). It's working ok.

I imported my map service into an OpenLayers map. It's working too, except that I'd like my ArcGIS93Rest layer to redraw every 30 seconds as well.

For now, I have to change zoom level to see the new tile with the new position.

I tried OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh, but either it's not working with Rest layers or I got it wrong...

```
var realtime = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest(
  "Temps réel",
  "http://xx.xx.xx.x:6080/arcgis/rest/services/trains_rt/MapServer/export",
     {transparent: "true", format: "image/png"},
     {isBaseLayer: false, singleTile: true, visibility: true, format: "image/png"},
     {strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({interval: 10000, force: true})]}
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like OpenLayers `strategies` are only available for [`Vector`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html) type Layers, and not [`ArcGIS93Rest`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/ArcGIS93Rest-js.html) type Layers.